# oracle on delete cascade with condition

Tags: oracle, triggers, foreign-keys

I have a foreign key in the table B to the table A. what I want, is on removing record in A, use cascade delete OR cascade set NULL in the FK field in B depends on the value in some column of that record, that should be removed.

As far as I cant use condition in delete cascade, my ideas was to always use cascade SET NULL and add trigger to table B

```
AFTER UPDATE..
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :new.a = 1 THEN
       DELETE FROM B WHERE ID = :new.id
   ENDIF;
END;
```

But I get an error, smthing like "table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it".

So, I've changed my if-else to procedure call

```
AFTER UPDATE
BEGIN
    cleanup_table_b();
END;

create or replace procedure cleanup_table_b
IS begin    
    DELETE FROM B WHERE a = 1;    
end;
```

But still get an error ORA-04091, ORA-06512, ORA-04088

The business idea of that, is the records in B can still be usefull (not by foreign keys) or not, so I want to perform a cleanup and remove useness records.

Comment: Use a on delete trigger on table A to delete or set null the referencing records in table B.

Comment: @Rene yeah, but thats making one table to maintain another one. Better structure solution would be if a table can maintain itself

Comment: You have to explain why you think that's "better".

Comment: You have to have the trigger on table A, because otherwise how would table B know it needs to do something to maintain itself?

Comment: You could get around the mutating table in [the usual way](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions), but I can't see how that would help.  How does your trigger know that the row with a=1 was updated by a cascaded delete from table A, and not just by a simple update?

Comment: @Rene Sure. For example for a some day in a 2-3 year i'd like to break that relation at all. Moreover, records in table A can be removed as the result of some complex operation, consisting of lots of other removing in tables relatives to A. How do u think whould it be clear for me to understand why removing records in some bunch table removes records in my completely INDEPENDENT table B? First what I'd do is to scan for triggers in B itself. In case of ur design I have to scan for all avaibale triggers in my DB to find the required one.

Comment: @Boneist "understanding" is simple. Set for FK in B parameter "ON DELETE SET NULL", and add trigger to B: "AFTER UPDATE", if "column value is null", than B has to maintain itself.

Comment: @TonyAndrews By business, NULL value can not be set in column with FK, so, if it has NULL value - cascade delete was performed

Comment: You are mistaken in thinking that table B is independent of table A.

Comment: Because if it were you wouldn't be asking this question here. Something changes in A and now there is a need for action on table B.

Comment: NULL value **can** be set in column with FK, as long as the column allows nulls.

Comment: @Rene Yes, now it is dependent. I wanted to say that some day it can become independent

Answer (score 0):

The following desicion was implemented. Been used a "on delete" trigger on table A to delete or set null the referencing records in table B. So delete trigger ran a cleanup of B